# how to switch between chrome pop ups frame using selenium ( python )

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I can't go to the second frame and press the choose files button.

I use this code, but it stops at the stage of switching between tires. I don't know if the problem is from selecting the element or what??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwhFL.png)

```
import undetected_chromedriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
profile = "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1"
options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={profile}")
options.add_argument("--maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, use_subprocess=True)


try:
    driver.get("https://www.blogger.com/blog/post/edit/8939316404502578286/7682105727870001806")
    time.sleep(2)

    # Insert image
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='ytEBO']").click()
    time.sleep(2)

    # Upload from computer
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@data-command='imageUploadPicker']").click()
    time.sleep(2)

    # Switch to iframe
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='ml5bvv4zihxz']"))
    time.sleep(2)

    # Choose files Btn
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='.goog-inline-block.jfk-button.jfk-button-   standard']").click()
    time.sleep(2)

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Please help and thank you.